# Create Java array Objects using jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, minecraft-forge

I'm creating a Minecraft mod using jruby, in the moment, i'm trying make new recipes but i get this error:

```
NameError: no method 'addRecipe' for arguments (org.jruby.proxy.net.minecraft.block.Block$Proxy0,org.jruby.java.proxies.ArrayJavaProxy) on Java::CpwModsFmlCommonRegistry::GameRegistry
```

This is the correct way to do this in java:

```
GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Items.apple), new Object[]{
            "XXX",
            "XYX",
            "XXX",
            'X', Items.arrow,
            'Y', Items.bone
        });
```

This is my ruby code:

```
GameRegistry.addRecipe(newBlock, ["XYX",'X',Items.apple,'Y',Items.redstone].to_java)
```

This is the addRecipe function(from GameRegistry class)

```
public static void addRecipe(ItemStack output, Object... params)
{
        addShapedRecipe(output, params);
}
```

AddShapedRecipe function:

```
public static IRecipe addShapedRecipe(ItemStack output, Object... params)
{
        return CraftingManager.getInstance().addRecipe(output, params);
}
```

How to create the array object in ruby and export to java?

thanks

Comment: Did you `require` the appropriate jar file? I think you have to reference the full jar path, for example: `com.example.GameRegistry.addRecipe(...)`

Comment: probably an issue related to your `newBlock` variable, does it wrap a `ItemStack` java type ?